# Pycharm with Electron - runnerw.exe: CreateProcess failed with error 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: node.js, pycharm, electron

I just try to start Electron app on Windows with [Electron Quick Start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) .

How to fix this error when running Electron on PyCharm?

```
runnerw.exe: CreateProcess failed with error 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

**PS**: I am running on Windows 10 x64

**My Electron Configuration**
[image: My Electron Configuration]
**My Error**
[image: My Error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `\.bin\electron.cmd` instead of `\.bin\electron` in **Node interpreter** configuration

Hope this help.

Comment: Is there any insight on what path variable may throw the error when it is a pycharm-docker integration?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Git in Intellij IDEA, when I change a path in settings on C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe - it works now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when installing PyCharm.
When click on "Configure", I had set the path to "C:\Program Files\Git", that is where I installed Git in my computer.
It turns out that the executable file is in "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe", so I made the explicit reference and now it works